# Find a value that is between the preceding and following values in subsets of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to find a row of a specific transaction type that follows a row of a different transaction type. The problem I have is that the table in question can contain multiple instances of each transaction type for an entity and I want to pair the transactions up sequentially.

Once I have identified the pairs of transactions, I then want to copy a date value from the first transaction type to the matched row of the second transaction type.

Here is a table which demonstrates the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Example]
(
    [EntityID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionSequenceNumber] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionType] [VARCHAR](1) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 1, 'A', '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 2, 'B', '2017-01-02 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 3, 'C', NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 4, 'B', '2017-01-03 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 5, 'C', NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (1, 6, 'D', '2017-01-05 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 1, 'A', '2017-02-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 2, 'B', '2017-02-02 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 3, 'C', NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 4, 'B', '2017-02-10 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 5, 'C', NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (2, 6, 'B', '2017-02-13 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (3, 1, 'A', '2017-03-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (3, 2, 'B', '2017-03-02 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Example ( EntityID, TransactionSequenceNumber, TransactionType, TransactionDate ) VALUES  (3, 3, 'C', NULL)
```

In this example, I want to update the type 'C' rows with the date from the preceding type 'B' row.

Here is a select query which demonstrates the flaw with my current query:

```
SELECT  
    c.EntityID, c.TransactionSequenceNumber, c.TransactionType,  
    b.EntityID, b.TransactionSequenceNumber, b.TransactionDate 
FROM    
    dbo.Example c
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         EntityID,
         TransactionSequenceNumber,
         TransactionDate
     FROM   
         dbo.Example 
     WHERE  
         TransactionType = 'B') b ON b.EntityID = c.EntityID
                                  AND b.TransactionSequenceNumber < c.TransactionSequenceNumber
WHERE   
    c.TransactionType = 'C'
ORDER BY 
    c.EntityID, c.TransactionSequenceNumber
```

As you can see from the results, each 'C' is matched with every 'B' that has a lesser sequence number. How can I change my query to only pair each 'C' with the preceding 'B'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to get the right date:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Example A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM dbo.Example
             WHERE EntityID = A.EntityId
             AND TransactionSequenceNumber < A.TransactionSequenceNumber 
             AND TransactionType = 'B'
             ORDER BY TransactionSequenceNumber DESC) B
WHERE A.TransactionType = 'C'
;
```

If you want to update the date of the table, then use:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.TransactionDate = B.TransactionDate 
FROM dbo.Example A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM dbo.Example
             WHERE EntityID = A.EntityId
             AND TransactionSequenceNumber < A.TransactionSequenceNumber 
             AND TransactionType = 'B'
             ORDER BY TransactionSequenceNumber DESC) B
WHERE A.TransactionType = 'C'
;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!